# the installation screen freezes when i try to install ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb-installation

I am new to any OS apart from windows.

i tried to install ubuntu the option for what to do appears: try ubuntu, install ubuntu, etc.
when i try to install it the loading screen for ubuntu appears but after 15~ secs., the screen freezes and nothing happen, i have left my laptop for about 30 min and nothing happen.

i force shutdown and when i try to use the "try ubuntu" option the same happens...
i have a DELL Inspiron 15 7559;
i have tried with and without SECURE BOOT.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an issue with the boot disk? Try using a different USB drive or create a new DVD and see if the issue persists.

Comment: the error persists.....

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, take a picture to the frozen screen and show us**

I think the problem is in hardware. My friends had problems with hp leptops when they were trying to install ubuntu. I had the same problem when I was trying to install ubuntu on my acer (*I3; 4GB RaM; 320HDD {damaged};*)

***But meanwhile:***

**Fixes may help:**

1. Flash Bios to newest version and try after to install
2. Try older version of ubuntu, for example - 14.0
3. Change the instalation media type; If you have usb, try CD, or if you have a CD, try USB
4. Try different linux; For example manjaro or else.

Comment: the first part would be better suited as comment. pleas don't ask for information in answers. you could rewrite it to "lacking a screenshot, these fixes may help".  you might also want to suggest a *newer* linux, rather than an older one

Comment: Thanks for helping! I will be better next time.